# Generics: "Syntax error on token "extends", , expected"

Tags: java

First I tried:

```
public class WeightedEdge280<V> extends Edge280<V>{
```

Which gave me error:

```
"Bound mismatch: The type V is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <V extends Vertex280> of the type Edge280<V>"
```

So I tried:

```
public class WeightedEdge280<V> extends Edge280<V extends Vertex280>{...
```

Which gave me error:

```
"Syntax error on token "extends", , expected"
```

The edges class:

```
public class Edge280<V extends Vertex280> extends Pair280<V, V> {...
```

The assignment instructions:

```
The first step is to create the class for the custom edge object, let’s call it WeightedEdge280<V>. It should be an extension of Edge280<V>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to introduce the same bounds when you extend a generic class:

```
public class WeightedEdge280<V extends Vertex280> extends Edge280<V>
```

The reason is that you have declared that the generic type parameter in `Edge` `extends Vertex280`. When you create a class that extends `Edge` you need to ensure that its generic type parameter is also bounded at least as tightly. This is because the generic type of `WeightedEdge280` must always be a valid generic type for `Edge280`.

Otherwise I could do something like:

```
final WeightedEdge280<String>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean is:

```
public class WeightedEdge280<V extends Vertex280> extends Edge280<V>
```

The bounds should be specified where the generic parameter is defined.